# Why east-bound flight is faster than the reverse flight along the same route?

Tags: flight-planning

Compare

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Alaska+Airlines+764+yesterday+duration

and

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Alaska+Airlines+771+yesterday+duration

Why the east-bound flight is about 20% faster than the west-bound reverse flight?

Is it because of the average airflow is east-bound?